# Debian systemd and named, strange bug

Tags: debian, systemd, bind

I have setup named to use chroot, like Fedora and RockyLinux (-t /var/named/chroot).
The daemon works fine, only a little problem...the unit start, but systemd mark it as failed!

```
root@dns1:~# systemctl start named&
[1] 6158
root@dns1:~# 
root@dns1:~# pgrep -a named
6152 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind -t /var/named/chroot -4 -c /etc/named.conf
```

after two minutes..

```
root@dns1:~# jobs
[1]+  Running                 systemctl start named &
root@dns1:~# Job for named.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status named.service" and "journalctl -xeu named.service" for details.
```

the system is marked as "activating"

```
systemctl status named
● named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/service.d
             └─zzz-lxc-service.conf
     Active: activating (start) since Mon 2023-10-30 16:45:58 CET; 31s ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
   Main PID: 6165 (named)
     Memory: 9.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
             └─6165 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind -t /var/named/chroot -4 -c /etc/named.conf
```

This is the unit

```
cat named.service

[Unit]
Description=BIND Domain Name Server
Documentation=man:named(8)
After=network.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/named
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/rndc reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rndc stop
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=bind9.service
```

Comment: BTW: do not use: the & in `systemctl start named&`. Any string/status systemctl need to write to the console will suspend the command.  /var/log/bind/bind.log may contain further information.

Comment: Even using without & produce(d) the same error, and I also have the console busy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, with this simple syntax works fine

vim named.service

```
[Unit]
Description=BIND Domain Name Server
Documentation=man:named(8)
After=network.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -f -u named -t /var/named/chroot -u bind -c /etc/named.conf
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/rndc reload
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=bind9.service
```

Then I restart

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart named
```

Works fine, restart and reload

```
systemctl status named
● named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /run/systemd/system/service.d
             └─zzz-lxc-service.conf
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-10-30 19:43:58 CET; 1min 16s ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
   Main PID: 7218 (named)
     Memory: 9.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
             └─7218 /usr/sbin/named -f -u named -t /var/named/chroot -u bind -c /etc/named.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Type=notify
> ```

ah, this can't work – if you're letting BIND9 put itself into a chroot, it can't access the sockets needed to let systemd know it's started.

rocky 8.7 solves that by putting the `options {directory "/var/named"}` into the config file, instead of the command line, and explicitly stating pidfiles there. It still doesn't use `notify`, but `forking`.

Comment: Thanks but don't work